# nw-fileDialog Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I looked at other entries and problems people got faced and tried to solve mine but could not succeed. Somehow, I think I miss sth.

My html file looks like:

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html ng-app="IssueArchiver">
  <head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/angular-multi-select.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/nw-fileDialog.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="stylesheets/angular-multi-select.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">

  <title>Issue Archiver V1.0</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="stylesheets/IssueArchiver.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/IssueArchiver.js"></script>

   </head>

   <body>

        <div ng-controller="IssueArchiverCtrl"  >
         ...
        </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

My IssueArchiver.js source file looks like:

```
angular.module('IssueArchiver', ['multi-select'], ['DWand.nw-fileDialog'], ['ngRoute'])
.controller('IssueArchiverCtrl',['$scope', '$http', '$parse', 'fileDialog', function($scope, $http, $parse, fileDialog) {

....
}]);
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/modulerp0=IssueArchiver&p1=E…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.28%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A309)
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Module dependencies should go into one array:

```
angular.module('IssueArchiver', ['multi-select', 'DWand.nw-fileDialog', 'ngRoute'])
```